# Creating a seek bar to change brightness locks my screen in android 2.3.7

Tags: android

To be short, I'm trying to develop an android app to change brightness. I'm using seekBar to change the brightness. But, whenever my activity is created, my screen locks. I'm currently debugging in 2.3.7 (Cyanogen mod). But, it works fine in 4.0+ android devices.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
        //WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        if (arg0 == lvl_brightness) {
            if (progress < 10) {
                progress = 10;
                lvl_brightness.setProgress(10);
            }

            getWindow().getAttributes().screenBrightness = progress / 255; //<--- Problem here. If i comment from this line, my phone doesn't get locked
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, progress);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will work. Try adding a 'f' to the denominator:

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
        if (arg0 == lvl_brightness) {
            if (progress < 10) {
                progress = 10;
                lvl_brightness.setProgress(10);
            }

            getWindow().getAttributes().screenBrightness = progress / 255f; //Add f 
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, progress);

        }

    }
```

Try and post your comment